# PhpStorm light yellow highlight in file explorer / project window, what is it and how can I change the color?

Tags: phpstorm

I just started using PhpStorm, and I've noticed when I look into my `vendor` directory (managed by Composer), I see the background colour is a light yellow and unreadable with my current theme. It like this in all the directories within the `vendor` folder.

#### What does it mean? How can I change the background color?

[image: light yellow background in project window composer vendor]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This color usually means that such files are not part of the project itself.

In you case this means that the folder is excluded and then re-added back to the project as External Library (via `PHP | Inlude paths` functionality) -- this way you do not see ToDos from them in your ToDo list; your own code refactoring does not affect/mess up with libraries and other stuff like that.

---

You can edit colors at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | File Colors`.

That particular color belongs to "Non-Project Files" scope.

Few options here.

- Change color of that scope entry (by double clicking on it) to any other that would fit your color scheme better.
- Disable highlighting files in Project View using background colors by unchecking the `Use in Project View` option.
- Use another GUI Theme that already provides more suitable/right colors.

Comment: And if you want to include the folder/file marked in yellow, right click > Mark Directory As > Cancel Exclusion

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that helped me was shutting down PhpStorm, removing the .idea folder and re-opening the project by dragging the root folder to PhpStorm (on a Mac).

Comment: Watch out! deleting .idea will remove all your preferences

Answer (score 0):

A super late answer, because I faced the very same problem right now, in the hope that future readers would be helped: if *all* the files in your project have a yellow background, it could mean that phpstorm couldn't find the right configuration for the project (it happened to me after changing the project's name). In this case, you can open the file `.idea/modules.xml` and look at the "fileurl" and "filepath" attributes. there should be two paths pointing to a ".iml" file: if these two paths are different from the one found in the .idea directory, you can change their name to match the "real" IML file, or change that IML file to match the name found in the path. Making them coherent solves the issue of "oh, gosh, all your files do not belong to this project".