# My directory in PhpStorm have yellow background

Tags: phpstorm

My directory in PhpStorm have this yellow contrast. What can I do to remove this?

[image: Directory Image]

Comment: Yellow directories are what will be ignored by git, usually listed in .gitignore, or are "non-project files". This is fine. If you don't like the color, you can change it or disable it in your settings under Appearance & Behavior > File Colors

Comment: Yellow background means that PhpStorm treats that folder as excluded/outside of the project one. Please check your folders -- perhaps you have marked it as Excluded somehow: `Settings/Preferences | Directories`

Comment: If it's all good there -- perhaps your project settings are corrupted somehow. In such a case I may suggest to: 1) close this project in IDE; better even exit the IDE; 2) open your PROJECT_ROOT folder in your file manager and backup & delete `.idea` subfolder (it contains this project settings); 3) Start PhpStorm and open that project again. You may need to use `Open` (point to the project root folder). PhpStorm will make a brand new project from those existing files so you will need to re-configure it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.idea` directory which contain PHPStorm project settings seem to be corrupted. This dark-yellowish background marks files that do not belong to your project.

Try deleting `.idea` from outside your IDE using `rm -rf .idea` and reopen your project with `File > Open..`

Another way PHPStorm provides to solve issues like this could be using `File > Repair IDE..`

As this question seems to be a duplicate, I also found [this useful stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25298136/15484481).

Answer (score 0):

Yellow background under folder/file name means that it is excluded/outside of the project.

You have multiple options:

- List them in **.gitignore** since they are really local, are nice to have, should not be vomited/pushed to repository
- **revert** or delete them, but then you will lose your local configurations. E.g. in your case:
- - .idea is IDE configuration
- - .env you local devhost configuration
- - vendor consists vendor files downloaded by 'composer install'
- include them (via **Settings/Preferences -> PHP -> Inlude paths**. [See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297629/phpstorm-light-yellow-highlight-in-file-explorer-project-window-what-is-it-an).
- Set content root: **Settings/Preferences -> Directories -> add**. Sometimes all folders are yellow -- bug, root folder should be set. Or needed folders are yellow -- please check your folders as @LazyOne told -- perhaps you have marked them as Excluded somehow.